# How to change the data of an existing D3 visualization and perform a transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have created a visualization elements  with the following code and it display everything as expected:

```
var linkTopicComments = vis.selectAll(".linktopics")
  .data(topicLinks)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "linktopics")
  .attr("d", topicDiagonal)
  .attr("opacity", "0.3");
```

Later, I update the associated data using the following code, which simply changes the value of x coordinate.In this code `topicLinks` is global and `vis` is my visualization

```
for (var i = 0; i < topicLinks.length; i++) {
  topicLinks[i].source.x-=25;
}
```

Finally, I updated the visualization using the following code:

```
var linkTopicComments = vis.selectAll(".linktopics")
  .data(topicLinks)
  .transition();
```

Unfortunately nothing updates.  any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In D3, `selection.transition` creates a transition from a initial state to a final state. For instance...

```
selection.attr("foo", 1)//initial state
    .transition()
    .attr("foo", 20)//final state
```

... transitions the attribute `foo` from 1 to 20. By the way since we didn't set any duration, the default 250 milliseconds duration will be applied.

In your case...

```
var linkTopicComments = vis.selectAll(".linktopics")
    .data(topicLinks)
    .transition();
```

... you're not transition anything, since there is nothing in the chain after `transition()`, and the semicolon corroborates that.

The solution is quite simple: explicitly tell D3 what do you want to transition. For instance:

```
var linkTopicComments = vis.selectAll(".linktopics")
    .data(topicLinks)
    .transition()
    .attr("d", topicDiagonal);
```

Comment: thanks that worked. Another thing that i need help with is that i have to **re draw** same visualization based on a **new criteria**. i cannot figure out how can i shuffle / re-draw whole vis?  I have a running visualization and i need to sort whole visualization using new critreria ? how can that be achieved in D3?

Comment: Please post this as a new question, with the relevant details.